# iOS 11 - Navigationbar large title custom offset

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios11, uinavigationitem

Is it possible to change the x-offset of the large navigation bar title? I would like to change the x-offset to 36pt.

[image: The navigation bar]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I just discovered in the latest version of iOS 12, if you simply modify the `layoutMargins` property of the `UINavigationBar`, this will affect the large title.

```swift
let navigationBar = navigationController.navigationBar
navigationBar.layoutMargins.left = 36
navigationBar.layoutMargins.right = 36
```

I tried the solution mentioned here about using a custom `NSMutableParagraphStyle`. That does indeed work, but because it stretches the `UILabel` view that the large title is made of, when you swipe downwards, the subtle animation it plays where the text grows slightly becomes quite distorted.

Comment: Great tip. This also works if you are using a search bar: `searchController.searchBar.layoutMargins.left = X`.

Comment: Great point about NSMutableParagraphStyle approach issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You can add additional offset this way:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.alignment = .justified
    style.firstLineHeadIndent = 18
    navigationBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: style]
}
```

Comment: This broke for me with long titles. I added `style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You need to write your own NavigationController, by subclassing the UINavigationController for that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to subclass the UINavigationBar, then override the draw method, and inside make the changes. Have a look at my working example and then adjust the offset/styles as you need:

```
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let largeView = "_UINavigationBarLargeTitleView"
    let labelcolor = UIColor(red: 36.0/255.0, green: 38.0/255.0, blue: 47.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    for view in self.subviews {
        if largeView.contains(String(describing: type(of: view))) {
            for v in view.subviews {
                if String(describing: type(of: v)) == "UILabel" {
                    var titleLabel = v as! UILabel
                    var labelRect = titleLabel.frame
                    let labelInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 13, bottom: 0, right: 0)
                    let attrText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Jobs", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Heavy", size: 30)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: labelcolor])

                    labelRect.origin.y += 20
                    let newLabel = UILabel(frame: labelRect)
                    newLabel.attributedText = attrText
                    titleLabel.text = ""
                    if labelRect.origin.y > 0 {
                        titleLabel = newLabel
                        titleLabel.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(labelRect, labelInsets))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## SwiftUI

You can adjust the layout margin across your entire app in the `AppDelegate`

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil
    ) -> Bool {
        // Adjust left margin
        UINavigationBar.appearance().layoutMargins.left = 36
        
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct testApp: App {
    // Attach AppDelegate
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```